# sending 'this' as parameter from web controls to javascript functions

Tags: javascript, asp.net

i have a function like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" >
    function postBack(e) {
        var lnk=document.getElementById('<%=e.getAttribute("ClientID") %>');
        lnk.click();
    };
</script>
```

and have a link button like this:

```
<asp:LinkButton onfocus="postBack(this);" id="lnk_home" runat="server" 
     AccessKey="h" onclick="lnk_home_Click">Home</asp:LinkButton>
```

I want to redirect page when i press Alt+h
But it does not work. I get the following error when i press Alt+h:

[Compiler Error Message: CS0103: The name 'e' does not exist in the current context]

Any suggestions about how to fix this problem? Thanks

UPDATE**
Server side code:

```
protected void lnk_home_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        home home_view = LoadControl("home.ascx") as home;
        Panel pnl_view = (Panel)ContentPlaceHolder1.FindControl("pnl_view");
        //pnl_view.Controls.Clear();
        pnl_view.Controls.Add(home_view);
    }
```

Comment: do you intend for users to click the link too?

Comment: no, I want Click event of the linkButton to be handled when user presses alt+h

Comment: why have a click event at all then? just call `lnk_home_Click` inside `postBack`. also, see this fiddle (press alt-h to test): http://jsfiddle.net/ChxMS/ - the problem is not with passing `this` to `postBack`, it's elsewhere

Comment: the problem is that you are mixing client-side variable `e` in `function postBack(e)` with server-side code between `<%` and `%>` tags. They don't exist at the same time. `this` in `onfocus="postBack(this);"` is also a client-side DOM element and not server-side control reference.

Comment: Its not just one button, I have say 10 buttons.Should I do that for all the buttons?

Comment: I cant call Click event of link button using JavaScript. How can i do that? document.getelementbyid(elementid).click() doesn't work at all. ahhhhh

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need a separate JavaScript function, just use `this.click()`:

```
<asp:LinkButton onfocus="this.click()" id="lnk_home" runat="server"  AccessKey="h" onclick="lnk_home_Click">Home</asp:LinkButton>
```

Or if you do want to use a separate function (perhaps to perform some common routine on multiple LinkButtons) invoke `click method` on passed object itself:

```
<asp:LinkButton onfocus="postBack(this);" id="lnk_home" runat="server" AccessKey="h" onclick="lnk_home_Click">Home</asp:LinkButton>

<script type="text/javascript" >
    function postBack(oLink) {
        // some common code
        oLink.click();
    };
</script>
```

**UPDATE** When you actually click the link with the mouse - event may fire twice, so you need to limit it to one click:

```
<asp:LinkButton onfocus="this.AllowClick=true;this.click();" OnClientClick="if (this.AllowClick) {this.AllowClick=false} else {return false}"  id="lnk_home" runat="server"  AccessKey="h" onclick="lnk_home_Click">Home</asp:LinkButton>
```

Comment: it worked but after a while I dont know why it threw the following exception:  JavaScript runtime error: Sys.ParameterCountException: Parameter count mismatch. Any help please?

Comment: I don't think it's related to above code, `this.click()` is very basic. But just in case try in the second approach instead of just `oLink.click()` use `setTimeout(function(){oLink.click()},10);`

Comment: Error again. olink is undefined. Its really getting me exhausted :(

Comment: i hasten to add that whole the content is whithin updatepanel and i use ajax.

Comment: You said that link button does redirect to home page. Can you update your question with server-side code to show server-side `Click` event and how it does the redirect?

Comment: Yuriy your helps are really appreciated.It's working now but I'm not sure how long it's gonna last!My goal was to set a shortcut key for a linkbutton so user could work easily with keyboard like WinFomrs.

Comment: That server-side code is pretty straightforward too. Again I don't think the error is related to programmatic click. Monitor it and if the error happens again - see if it happens on normal click.

Comment: When I remove <onfocus="this.click()> it works but when i add it again to my link button it works when I press Alt+h but it throws an error when I click on it.

Comment: I think this is happening because when you click the link - "click" fires twice, both for focus and for click. Try using this for your linkbutton: (I've updated my answer with this code as well) `<asp:LinkButton onfocus="this.AllowClick=true;this.click();" OnClientClick="if (this.AllowClick) {this.AllowClick=false} else {return false}"  id="lnk_home" runat="server"  AccessKey="h" onclick="lnk_home_Click">Home</asp:LinkButton>`